# Change SystemParameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

Just a quick question: What exactly is the SystemParameters class? Is it just a collection of "default values" or is it actually kind of hooked into windows?

Background: For Drag&Drop operations we are using the SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance and SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance properties to detect D&D. For Touch screens the default values are to small and I'm wondering if I have to implement some configuration mechanism to change this values or if I can change some system settings somewhere (lets say registry or control panel or whatever).

Thanks!

Update: With the detailed answer below I finally did find what I ws looking for. Just for reference if anybody else is looking for it in the future: The Minimum Drag Distance can be changed in the registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\DragHeight
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\DragWidth
```

By default both values are set to 4 (px). Be aware that the changes only take effect after reboot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It reflects the user's current settings, as specified in various places throughout Windows.** Some settings are easily changed by the user in the Control Panel, and others are located in more obscure places like Registry values.

Ultimately, it is a managed wrapper around the [`GetSystemMetrics` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385.aspx) from the Windows API.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) provides more specific details on where it obtains each of the values exposed by properties. For example, the [`SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.minimumhorizontaldragdistance.aspx) corresponds to the width of a rectangle centered on a drag point to allow for limited movement of the mouse pointer before a drag operation begins. Essentially, it's the "leeway" that the user is allowed to bump or jostle the cursor around before the system interprets their action as beginning a drag.

The documentation also tells you that it maps to `SM_CXDRAG` in the `GetSystemMetrics` function. So if you need even more detailed information, you can peruse the documentation for the native function, which tells you the following:

> The number of pixels on either side of a mouse-down point that the mouse pointer can move before a drag operation begins. This allows the user to click and release the mouse button easily without unintentionally starting a drag operation. If this value is negative, it is subtracted from the left of the mouse-down point and added to the right of it.

In short, it is definitely "hooked into Windows". This is the appropriate way to determine system settings, rather than hard-coding values that seemed desirable at development time. Your application should not expose its own configuration interface for things that the system already allows the user to configure; that's both redundant and confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the very detaild answer! I am well aware about what the parameter is doing and what it is used for. I was actually looking for the place where to set it in the system. On the other hand ... I didn't ask for it specifically :) and your answer got me on the right track !

Comment: @harri: Ack! Remember that you shouldn't be modifying the Registry directly to change settings like this. There's [a documented API for it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/10/9541813.aspx). You want the `SystemParametersInfo` function, with the `SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT` and `SPI_SETDRAGWIDTH` parameters.

Comment: The thing is: I don't want to write code to change the setings. The request to increase the D&D distance came from our testers when they tested the application on a touch screen. With a touch screen its nearly impossible to click on an item without starting an D&D operation. But this issue is not specific to the software but to the whole system. So I don't want our software to adjust the values. It rather should be done for the whole OS and it would be kind of confusing.